# Why is ($\mathbb R$,usual) not homeomorphic to ($\mathbb R$,discrete)?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

1. Why is ($\mathbb R$,usual) not homeomorphic to ($\mathbb R$,discrete)?

   ($\mathbb R$,discrete) means $d(x,y) =1$ for any $x\neq y$ and $d(x,y) =0$ for all $x=y$, both $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb R$.
2. Is ($\mathbb R$,discrete) homeomorphic to ($\mathbb R$,usual)? Why?
3. $M$ is homeomorphic to $N$ means there exists a mapping $f$, both one to one and continuous while onto not necessary, from $M$ to $N$, is that right?

Comment: Regarding your question #3: no, it's not right.  Homeomorphic means there is a continuous mapping $f$ from $M$ to $N$ that is invertible and whose inverse is also continuous.  Since $f$ has an inverse, it must also be onto.

Comment: If you answer 1 you have answered 2.

Comment: @1234 You should recognize that editing old questions pushes them to the front page; this is a cost to editing, and is why it is preferable if you only make substantial edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using a convention that I am not familiar with, your definition of homeomorphism is not correct. A [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) is a bijective continuous function with continuous inverse.

You can show that homeomorphisms form an equivalence relation. Thus $(\mathbb{R},$ usual$)$ being homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},$ discrete$)$ us equivalent to $(\mathbb{R},$ discrete$)$ being homeomorphic to $(\mathbb{R},$ usual$)$. In particular, your (1) and (2) are therefore the same question.

One reason why $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology is that everything is disconnected in the discrete topology, while everything is connected in the typical topology. Connectedness is preserved by continuous maps, so there is no continuous map from typical onto discrete.

Answer (score 3):

For 3)No a homeomorphism is continuous,bijective and the inverse is continuous.So the inverse of a homeomorphism is homeomorphism itself,which implies that the relation "is homeomorphic to" is an equivalence relation.For this reason 2) and 1) are equivalent.

2)In discrete topology every set with one element is open therefore every subset is open as union of open sets and for the same reason its complement is open.So all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are open and closed in discrete topology.
Of course this is not true in the usual topology sets with one element are not open.But if there was a homeomorphism from ($\mathbb{R}$,discrete) $\to \mathbb{R}$ then it should map the open set $\{x\} $ to an open set.But $f(\{ x\})=\{ f(x)\}$ which is not open,a contradiction.Thus there is no such homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Because everything is clopen in $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology.
$(0,1)$ is not closed in the usual.
2. The answer is no. Homeomorphisms are open maps. 
3. You need a continuous bijection whose inverse is also continuous.

Comment: Why is (0,1)  closed in $\mathbb R$ with the discrete topology?

Comment: @Frank_W: In the discrete topology, *every* set is open, and *every* set is closed.

Comment: @MJD: If $Ball_ε$(x) ∩ F ≠ empty, and x belongs to F, then F is closed. So for any discrete space, ε has been fixed to a value. Since $Ball_ε$(x) ∩ F ≠ empty for the fixed ε, every set will be closed in the discrete space, is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W Do you know why every set is open?

Comment: @Luis:U is open if given x belongs to U, there is some ε>0 such that $Ball_ε$(x) belongs to U. Since ($Ball_ε$(x)\x) belongs to ($\mathbb R$\x) for the fixed ε(for example, ε=1), every set will be open, is that right?

Comment: @Frank_W I don't know what you mean by "for any discrete space, ε has been fixed to a value". There are balls in a discrete space also.  For example, $Ball_{1/2}(x)$ is the set of all points $y$ that are closer than $1/2$ to $x$; this is the set $\{x\}$ because every other $y$ is at distance 1 from $x$.  And $Ball_{17}(x)$ is the set of all points $y$ that are closer than $17$ to $x$; this is the set that contains every point.  The definition of balls is the same, but because the definition of distance is different, the balls look quite different than they do in the usual space.

Comment: @MJD: Im sorry I've made a mistake on the definition of ball in discrete space. U r right, thanks a lot. So $Ball_ε$(x) ∩ F ≠ empty for any ε >0  in discrete space. But ($Ball_ε$(x) ∩ F"=empty) contains more than 1 point only when ε >1, is that right?

Comment: $\{x\}=B_\frac{\epsilon}{2}(x)$. Hence, singletons are open. Since arbitrary unions of open sets are open, and the fact that any set can be written as the union of singletons, any set is open. Now, $(0,1)=\mathbb{R}-((-\infty,0]\cup[1,\infty))$. Hence it is the complement of an open set and thus closed.